How do I resolve GitHubCLI 'signatures are invalid' error on apt upgrade?
I'm running sudo apt upgrade and getting this error:
W: Failed to fetch https://cli.github.com/packages/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG XXXXXXXXXXX GitHub CLI <opensource+cli@github.com>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Invalid operation ugprade```

`XXXXXXXXX` replaces id

How do I best resolve?


Have you taken a look at this Github issue ?
